# How to check for a string in csv files for verifying users in python

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to work out how to look for matching words in a csv file, such a user account detail.

What I have already done is creating two csv files with a username in one and a password in the other, putting them into python and then create a script that lets the user log in, but I can't get it to search for just one username if there are more than one in the csv file.

Here is my code:

```
import csv

#imports and loads usernames and passwords
usernames = []
passwords = []

infile = open("usernames.csv",'r')
reader=csv.reader(infile)
for i in reader:
    usernames.append(i)
infile.close()

infile = open("passwords.csv",'r')
reader=csv.reader(infile)
for i in reader:
    passwords.append(i)
infile.close()

#the log in script
def login():
    print("Please enter your username:")
    userlogin=input()
    print("Please enter your password:")
    passlogin=input()
    if userlogin in usernames and passlogin in passwords:
        print("Welcome, " + userlogin)
    else:
        print("Sorry, that's not a valid login")
```

Thank you for any help given

Comment: What do your csv files look like? Why are there two separate files for usernames and passwords? I would think there would be one file that contains both the username and the corresponding password on the same line. Otherwise how do you know which password goes with which username? Storing them in a dictionary would also be better than two separate list variables.

Comment: How do you pair a username to a password? Why do you have two separate files for this? What is even point of using a CSV file if you're not going to take advantage of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a flaw in your approach.

You cannot combine any username with any password.

If you are going to use your code this way,

One password will become applicable for all.

Try to create a dictionary or some kind of mapping where a single password will be checked instead of all present passwords.

If you want to add them, I would suggest using a pandas dataframe which will give you structure and checking will be easier as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['usernames'] = pd.read_csv('usernames.csv')
df['passwords'] = pd.read_csv('passwords.csv')

if df[(df['usernames'] == your_user_name) & 
(df['passwords'] == your_password)].empty() is not True:
  print("username and password present")
else:
  print("username and password not present")
```